# WPF XAML textbox caret position at the End

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

Im devloping an Application which uses a lot auf Textboxes. If they got focus the Caret is at the first position of the Textbox. Even if already text exists. 
Im searching for a soloution to set the caret at the end of the text FOR ALL Texbox, when they got focus.

I know, that I can handle the GotFocus()-Event and then set the position manually. But is there a smarter soloution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is using Event handler as you said.

```csharp
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
}
```

Then assign this Event handler to each `TextBox`.

The `CaretIndex` in generic `TextBox` is not a property. Thus the smarter solution need at least creation of a custom Control inherited from `TextBox`. You may make `CaretIndex` a property this way. Then just use `Style.Triggers` in xaml with Property `IsFocused`.